# Custom tab not showing when using the Custom UI Editor

Tags: templates, customization, word-2007

I have a few buttons that I wish to add to a custom tab in Word 2007 (adding to the `normal.dotm` template, using the Custom UI Editor), to complete some actions that I have scripted, but I cannot get the tab to show up.

I've used this method several times for individual projects, and it works fine, but adding the below to `normal.dotm` is not working.

The code verifies fine, so I don't think there are any errors. Does anybody know why this would not work? Thanks.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="tabCustomActions" label="Custom Actions">
                <group id="groupTLA" label="TLA">
                    <button id="startTLA" label="Format for TLA" imageMso="startTLA" size="large" onAction="on_action" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it on an empty .docm file and it worked for me, although the image didn't show up but I am guessing it is a custom icon?

I ran it using Word 2007.

It is strange, since I have been trying to insert a ribbon into Excel all day it has not worked, yet I did a different custom ribbon numerous times last week using the same procedure.

I would suggest finding the most recent Custom UI Editor, dated August 2010. The version number didn't change, but it is definitely newer.

This version is the one dated August 2010, and while some of the comments say it doesn't work for 2007, I believe it does if done correctly.

Comment: To be honest, I'd forgotten all about this! Have just revisited, and un-installed then re-installed the Custom UI Editor, and now it works. Crazy and slightly frustrating, but at least it's up and running. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Glad to help when I can David.